# Is there any method to re-render the API data again after form values updated in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

Below is the code of my MemberInformation component, I am fetching data from the API to display member information in the useeffect.
This component has an update information option to which allow the displayed member information to be updated.

```
export default function MemberInformation() {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const[memberData,setMemberData]=useState([]);
    const [member,setMember]=useState({_id:"",refmno:"",name:"",surname:"",email:"",phone:"",address:"",postcode:"",state:"",country:"",
    bankaccinfo:"",memberno:"",payAud:"",password:"",date:""})


        var name,value;
        const handleInputs=e=>{
          console.log("Updated ",member)
          name=e.target.name;
          value=e.target.value;
          setMember({...member,[name]:value})
        }
```

When this postData function is called, the updated values will be posted to the back-end API and should display the updated values again but it is displaying older values. Even after page refresh, it doesn't refetch the API in useeffect

```
       const postData= ()=>{
            // e.preventDefault();
            alert("working");       const{_id,refmno,name,surname,email,phone,address,postcode,state,country,bankaccinfo,memberno,
password,payAud,date}=member;
          var UpdatedMemInfo ={_id, refmno,name,surname,email,phone,address,postcode,
state,country,bankaccinfo,memberno,password,payAud,date};
          axios.post('/memberInfoUpdate', UpdatedMemInfo)
          .then( res => {
            alert('Updated successfully!');
           }   
          )
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err.response);
            alert('An error occurred! Try submitting the form again.');
          });
       }
```

In the useeffect I cannot enter memberData in the [memberData ] to refetch anychanges made in the API because if I do so then the values displayed in the Modal are continuously fetching data i.e. not allowing me to change the values.
The member usestate contains the values to be displayed in modal input values.

```
useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchBooks() {
          const response = await fetch('/memberinfo');
          const json = await response.json();
          setMemberData(json.memberInfo);
          setMember(json.memberInfo);
          console.log(json.memberInfo)
      }
      fetchBooks();
  },[]);
  return (
    <div className="xnarates">
        <h6 className="xnarateh6" >{t('Member Information')}</h6>
        <p className="xnaratep" >{memberData.name}'s {t('Personal Information')}</p>
        <div className="xnaratediv2">
        <p>{t('Edit Member Information')}</p>
        <i className="fa fa-pencil-square" onClick={()=>setShow(true)} style={{ fontSize: '1.75em' }} />
      </div>
        <Scrollbars className="scroller" style={{ width:390,height: 400 }}>
        <Table responsive style={{fontSize:"small"}}>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{t('Membership No.')}</td>
            <td>{memberData.memberno}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{t('Name')}</td>
            <td>{memberData.name}</td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
    </Table>
    </Scrollbars>
    {show==true?
      <Modal show={show}>
            <Modal.Header >
              <Modal.Title>Edit Member Information</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
              <Form >
              <Row >
                  <Col ><Form.Text className="text-muted">{t('Membership No.')}</Form.Text></Col>
                  <Col><Form.Control size="sm" type="text" name="memberno" placeholder="Enter Member No"  value={member.memberno}  disabled/></Col>
              </Row>
              <Row >
                  <Col ><Form.Text className="text-muted">{t('Name')}</Form.Text></Col>
                  <Col><Form.Control size="sm" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name" value={member.name} onChange={e=>handleInputs(e)}/></Col>
              </Row>
 </Form>
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
              <Button variant="danger" onClick={()=>setShow(false)}>
                Close
              </Button>
              <Button variant="success" onClick={()=>{setShow(false);postData()}}>
                Save Changes
              </Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
          </Modal>
  :""}
    </div>
  )
}
```

What I want is to:

1. display the values of member information in table.
2. when click on edit button, the modal opens, and if change some values there then it will be automatically displayed in the table after clicking on Save Changes button.

Is there any simpler option for it?

Comment: If your endpoint returns the updated object - you can reinitialize your state else you would need to do a refetch and set your state again.

Comment: how i can do a refetch?

Comment: Call the API again and insert the response into your state so your component can render the new data.

Comment: i had already tried this thing but the problem is that even after reloading the webpage the api is fetching previous data

Comment: The problem then is the api provider (your backend?) - It should return new data after performing a mutation

Comment: useeffect is fetching the previous data, even though the data had been updated at backend

Comment: did you check data via Postman? maybe your data is cached

Comment: yeah it was a back-end API issue, now it solved.